# R studio proxy / no proxy switching

Tags: r, github, proxy

R-studio integration with github works behind my corporate firewall when I set the proxy in the .Renviron file

```
http_proxy = http://<proxy>:80
https_proxy = http://<proxy>:80
```

In my case I don't need to specify user name and password, which I don't want hard coded anywhere.

When I work from home I get errors since R-studio is trying to find the proxy and failing.
Is it possible to write to the .Renviron file so that

Try using the proxy
if works then continue
if fails then ignore proxy settings and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you can use "[Conditional file and directory names](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html)"

> If the name of a file consists of a `<key>=<value>` specification, then that file will be included / used only if the specification is fulfilled (on the current system with the current R setup).
>
> For instance, a file `~/.Rprofile.d/os=windows.R` will be ignored unless `startup::sysinfo()$os == "windows"`, i.e. the R session is started on a Windows system.

you could use a customed rprofile filename to:

- unset HTTP(s)_proxy
- only if, for instance, `hostname=YourHomeLaptop`

That is

```
~/.Rprofile.d/nodename=YourHomeLaptop
```

---

If you are using the same laptop, use:

- `dirname`
- the same project with two clones of the same repository

You can use a different profile that way, with an easy git pull from one repository (for home work) to the other (for office work), and vice-versa.

Comment: This is a great resource. Since I'm using the same laptop at the office and at work, it would be great if there was a way for R to identify the Lan or Wifi name. I'm not seeing that in the link, but perhaps there is another variable I can use to distinguish if I'm in the office or not.

Comment: @JJRod You have `dirname`: if you work in different folders between your projects at work and your same project at home (two clones of the same repository), you could use a different profile that way.